# How do I collage booking date inputs and return as LocalDate format., and validate year/month/day values with a boolean?

Tags: java

How do I collage booking date inputs and return as LocalDate format in the getCarBookingDateFull() method, and validate year/month/day values with a boolean?  I tried date/time formatter  but couldn't get it to parse.  throws an exception.

I'm new to Java, so I'm not 100% across all concepts.  Many Thanks in advance.

```
package carrentalsystem;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

    
public class CarAndBookingDates {

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
int carSelection;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public void CarAndBookingDates() {
    
    this.year = 0000;
    this.month = 00;
    this.day = 00;
    this.carSelection = 0;
}

public int carSelection() {
    System.out.println("To make a booking:");
    System.out.println("\t" + "Select the car number from the car list:");
    carSelection = scan.nextInt();
    return carSelection;
}

public void setCarSelection(int carSelection){
    this.carSelection = carSelection;
}
public int getCarSelection(){
    return carSelection;
}
public int promptForYear() {
    System.out.println("\t" + "Enter booking start date.");
    System.out.println("\t"+"Please enter the year - for example '2020':");
    year = scan.nextInt();
    return year;
}
public void setpromptForYear(int year){
    this.year = year;
}
public int getpromptForYear(){
    return year;
}
public int promptForMonth() {
    System.out.println("\t"+"Please enter the month number - "
            + "for example '6':");
    month = scan.nextInt();
    return month;
}
public void setpromptForMonth(int month){
    this.month = month;
}
public int getpromptForMontrh(){
    return month;
}
public int promptForDay() {
    System.out.println("\t"+"Please enter the day number - "
            + "for example '21:");
    day = scan.nextInt();
    return day;
}
public void setpromptForDay(int day){
    this.day = day;
}
public int getpromptForDay(){
    return day;
}

public void getCarBookingDateFull() {
    String DayParsed = String.valueOf(day);
    String MonthParsed = String.valueOf(month);
    String YearParsed = String.valueOf(year);
    String TotalDate = DayParsed + MonthParsed + YearParsed;
    //LocalDate FullDateParsed = LocalDate.parse(DateParsed);
    //System.out.println(YearParsed +"/" + MonthParsed +"/" + DayParsed);
    
    //LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(TotalDate);
    
    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    try {
    LocalDate datetime = LocalDate.parse(TotalDate, pattern);
    System.out.println(datetime); 
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
       }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `LocalDate.parse()` like this:-

```
public static LocalDate getDate(int date, int month, int year) {  
    String strDate = ""+date;
    if(date < 9) {
        strDate = "0"+date;
    }
    
    String strMonth = ""+month;
    if(month < 9) {
        strMonth = "0"+month;
    }
    
    return LocalDate.parse(year+"-"+strMonth+"-"+strDate);
}
```

OR

Even you can use `LocalDate.of()` like this:-

```
public static LocalDate getDate(int date, int month, int year) {    
        return LocalDate.of(year,month,date);
    }
```

both the function will throw `DateTimeException` in the case of invalid date.

Comment: What about the validation part asked in the question?

Comment: @John The code shown validates the date and throws a `DateTImeParseException` of it is invalid. You will need to catch and handle it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        LocalDate datetime = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        System.out.println(datetime); 
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        System.out.println("Date is invalid: " + e);
    }
```

To show that it catches an incorrect date, I tried running this snippet before reading any numbers from the scanner (which of course is not how you will be using it). The output was:

> Date is invalid: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for
> MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0

After entering 2020 for year, 11 for month and 27 for day of month I got:

> 2020-11-27

**Further suggestions**

You may want to store the date as a `LocalDate` object in your `CarAndBookingDates` object. The user may prefer to enter it on one line rather than three numbers at three prompts after each other, for example like `27-11-2020` or `3-12-2020`. Then use the two-arg `LocalDate.parse(String, DateTimeFormatter)` for parsing the string that the user entered.

I think that `CarAndBookingDates` could advantageously assume the responsibility of prompting the use before returning any information to the caller. As the class stands now, the caller can forget to call the methods that prompt the user and would then just retrieve the default values.